# Mail Controller in iOS keeps on getting "cancelled"

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Only the email-subject is getting set to "Test mail" and recipients remain empty. MailController opens for a while and gives the alert as "Message Cancelled".
Anyone please help me out!

```
- (IBAction)sendEmail:(id)sender { //This is a button to send E-mail
    mailController=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    NSString *emailBody = @"Test mail from Fortune";
    [mailController setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hi@fortune.com",@"hello@fortune.com", nil]];
    [mailController setCcRecipients:@[@"gthg65@gmail.com"]];
    [mailController setBccRecipients:@[@"resumes@fortune.com"]];
    [mailController setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
    [mailController setSubject:@"Test mail "];
    mailController.mailComposeDelegate=self;
    [self presentViewController:mailController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSString *messageResult;
    if (error!=nil)
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Mail Error" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
    else{
        switch (result) {
            case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
                messageResult=@"Mail Cancelled";
                break;
            case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
                messageResult=@"Mail Failed";
                break;
            case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
                messageResult=@"Mail Saved";
                break;
            case MFMailComposeResultSent:
                messageResult=@"Mail Sent";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Mail Result" message:messageResult delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Test on a real device, not the simulator.

Comment: @rmaddy 1. why not on a simulator?
2. Can we test on a real device without a developers account?

Comment: Because you can't send email from the simulator and the simulator keeps giving you this problem.

Comment: 2. Can we test on a real device without a developers account?

Comment: In the past, no. But I think as of Xcode 7/iOS 9, Apple does allow a way.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you! :)

Comment: Unrelated - why the inconsistent approach to creating arrays? For the CC and BCC fields you use modern syntax but for the TO you use the old method.

Comment: @rmaddy This code was written by my tutor long back and today I was just testing it on my laptop.
That time he was explaining the two ways of creating an array and told both would work

Comment: @rmaddy Unrelated - I've just deployed my app on device but an error is showing up as "Untrusted developer ........... You can allow using these apps in settings".
Do you have any idea where it's? I've tried searching in developers tab in settings as well but of no use

Answer (score 0):

Works on a test device. Also Apple recently changed their developer account memberships and you can register for a free apple developer account and run the app on a test device that way.

Comment: I've just created a free apple developer id and connected my device but xcode is not recognizing it!?

Comment: What's the specific error? In Xcode preferences there's an accounts tab where you add your developer account. I suspect you didn't login there.

Comment: I've logged in there!
The specific error is:
Xcode cannot run using the selected device.
No supported iOS devices are available. Mark a device as “Use for Development” to run your application or choose a simulated device as the destination.

Comment: Fixed! Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: Getting an alert message as, 
"Untrusted developer", ..........., You can allow using these apps in settings.
Any idea where it is in the settings?